# Passing values into the `next` function in Redux Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux-saga

I have a saga:

```
export function* loadData() {
  const requestURL = 'http://www.web.address/thing';
  try {
    const data = yield call(getRequest, requestURL);
    yield put(dataLoaded(data));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(dataError(err));
  }
}
```

I'm trying to test it like this:

```
describe('loadData saga', () => {
  describe('200 response', () => {
    const getReq = jest.fn();
    const requestURL = 'mock.url.com';
    const generator = cloneableGenerator(loadData)();

    it('sends the request to the correct url', () => {
      expect(generator.next(getReq, requestURL).value).toEqual(call(getReq, requestURL));
    });
});
```

This test fails because the generator doesn't seem to heed what I pass into the next function, and I don't know why. That is to say, the test receives `http://www.web.address/thing` as the url, and the `getRequest` function, instead of what I've tried to pass in in the `.next()` function.

This also did not work:

```
generator.next(getReq(requestURL))
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You you shouldn't actually be passing any args into next() here, as your saga has no previous yields and doesn't pass any dynamic data from previous yield's to the `call` - it has everything it needs already in scope

So in your test you would check next().value is as expected using the non-mocked values

```
import {getRequest} from 'same/place/as/saga/loads/getRequest';
const requestURL = 'http://www.web.address/thing';

expect(generator.next().value).toEqual(call(getRequest, requestURL));
```

The problem you have is you are attempting to mock and pass in stubs which the saga has no way of injecting them in this case

Remember that a `yield` will stop execution of the generator until the next iteration so you are not actually running a request here, only stopping and receiving back an object of instructions of how to call `getRequest` with what args to pass.

Using `.next(someData)` after your above test will however allow you to pass in mock data as a simulation of the response of your request

```
const mockData = {};
expect(generator.next(mockData).value).toEqual(put(dataLoaded(mockData)))
```

Think of args to next() as allowing mocking the return value of the previous yield

Comment: "Think of args to next() as allowing mocking the return value of the previous yield" HERO. That's what I was missing thanks!